# Not calling UIImagePickerControl's methods by using AVCaptureSession in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, avcapturesession, photolibrary, avcapturedevice

I have used `AVCaptureSession` for capture photo in iPhone application. As well as I want to take an image from PhotosLibrary too.

I've implemented `UIImagePickerController` control and its all methods.

I can open library, But I can't get photo which I've selected. As well as not calling PickerView's methods. No response from those methods.

Is there any different way to implement `UIImagePickerController` control with `AVCaptureSession` for photos library?

Please tell me solution.

Or suggest me alternative solution instead of `Overlay` as I want both functionality with dynamic controls.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey, have you implemented all the delegate methods of both UIImagePickerController and AVCaptureSession???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For open photo library use this:

```
-(IBAction)pickphoto:(id)sender
{
    [self startMediaBrowserFromViewController: self usingDelegate: self];
}

- (BOOL) startMediaBrowserFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                               usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                               UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate{

    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil)
        || (controller == nil))
        return NO;

    UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

    mediaUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie,kUTTypeImage, nil];
    mediaUI.allowsEditing = YES;

    mediaUI.delegate = delegate;

    [controller presentModalViewController: mediaUI animated: YES];
    return YES;

}

- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info
{

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
 thumbnail = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And for capture a Image use this:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

imagePicker.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: In .h also declare UINavigationControllerDelegate & also mention this in .h file:- (BOOL) startMediaBrowserFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                               usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                               UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate;

Comment: I've tried with same UIImagePickerController but is there any difference in "- (BOOL) startMediaBrowserFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                               usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                               UINavigationControllerDelegate>)" method ??

Comment: I think perhaps. some day ago I am also stuck at this point then I am searching this method and implement it and it is working fine. I am also try like you.